# Difference between 觉得 and 认为

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I know both `觉得` and `认为` can be used to mean "to think", like:

> 你认为这篇文章怎么样？
>
> 你觉得这篇文章怎么样？

But most people would translate `觉得` to "to feel". Does `觉得` express more of what someone thinks based on just feeling, are there any cases where these two words are not interchangeable?

Comment: 觉得, to feel, to think. When 觉得 really means to feel, they are not interchangeable, e.g. `我觉得很累. I feel so tired.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, 觉得 expresses more of what someone thinks based on feeling. 认为 expresses more of a person's opinion based on considerations and beliefs. As such, 认为 is always stronger than 觉得 when communicating thoughts. There are cases where the two words are not interchangeable:

- When expressing a strong belief:

  > 在过去，人们**认为**喜欢抛头露面的妇女是不守妇道的。
  >  In the past, people considered women who
  >   appear in public to be lacking in virtue.
- When expressing a feeling:

  > 我**觉得**很遗憾，这件事不该发生的。
  >   I feel very sorry. This incident should not have happened.

Where they are meant to communicate thoughts, although interchangeable, there is always a preference of one over the other:

- When expressing a casual thought without a line of reasoning:

  > 我**觉得**这篇文章太深奥了，就算让我再读几遍我也读不懂。
  >  I feel that this article is too
  >   profound. I wouldn't be able to comprehend even if I read it a dozen
  >   times.
- When expressing an opinion with a clear line of reasoning:

  > 我**认为**这篇文章太深奥了，使用的词汇不是一般人都能看懂的。
  >  I opine that this article is too
  >   profound. The vocabulary used is not what an ordinary person can understand.

Comment: Based on @QuestionOverflow's post, I recommend a case-by-case learning process. For example, it's weird to say it as "我認為很遺憾，這件事不該發生的。", but it's quite natural to say "在過去，人們覺得，喜歡拋頭露面的婦女是不守婦道的。" To me, there's not so much difference between the two, but I really feel it a bit serious when I use 認為。